# Make js globally accessible to other dynamically loaded scripts

Tags: javascript, namespaces

i am developing an MVC site which has many partials that are dynamically loaded. On my site i have a sort of taskbar which sits at the top of the site.

I would like to be able to access methods and properties from my 'taskbar' from any dynamically loaded script.. What is the best way to go about this?

I understand that it is in scope but is there some preferred way to do namespacing or what is the best practice for handling this kind of issue? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scope it to the window usually, sometimes this needs to be explicit, sometimes it doesn't, for example:

```
window.Taskbar = {};
```

These should be available to use anywhere in your scripts (assuming they're logically in the same window).